# JFrame input to array, output to yml file

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, yaml

Is there any documentation or anyone who can help me understand how I would go about outputting data listed in an array that has been inputted via `JFrame` windows?

It needs to go into data fields like so:

```
#Name of the class, does not have to match the file name but is good practice.
name: [Array output 0]
#Is this the default join class?
default: [Array output 1]
#does this require a permission to be? (node.classname)
wildcard-permission: [Array output 2]
#Is this a primary or a secondary class? (primary are usually combat, secondary is crafting)
primary: [Array output 3]
#can it be a secondary?
secondary: false
#description shown in class lists.
description: The Default Starter Path
#Runs a cmd as console or not on selection of this class.
run-command:
  as-console: true
  #you can have multiple cmds run
  #use {player_name} for plugins who dont support @p, etc.
  command:
    -  [Array output]
    -  [Array output]
```

Comment: *"Is there any documentation or anyone who can help me understand how I would go about outputting data listed in an array that has been inputted via jframes(?)"* I doubt it. That is too specific. Try instead learning about writing files in particular formats and [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). Voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: BTW - *"Do recommend on if I post incorrectly and how I could fix it for my next post! .."* Since you can [edit] your question at any time, if it needs improving, do it now rather than in the next question!